# How can I make prevent multiple additions server-side - Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want only one entry in this table. Multiple records are created when the user clicks the button several times. I can do this client-side, no problem. But wouldn't it be safer to do it server-side. How can I wait for your help.

When I do it with javascript, the user can right click and examine and remove the code. So I want to make it server-side and secure it.

Do you think it is enough for me to do this only on the client side?

My seos table below

```
id|site_name  |site_description          | site_keywords                |
1 |Fibonaccci |Site Description Here...  | keyword, keyword1, keyword2  |




@extends('layouts.admin-panel.master')

@section('title', 'Fibonacci - Seo')

@section('content')

    <div class="content">
        <div class="page-inner">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4 class="page-title">Seo</h4>
                <ul class="breadcrumbs">
                    <li class="nav-home">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="flaticon-home"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="separator">
                        <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#">Seo</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title">Seo</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">

                                <form action="{{ route('seo.store') }}" method="POST" >
                                @csrf
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group p-0 margin-bottom-20 mt-0">
                                                <label for="name">Site Title (Characters left: 70)<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                                                <input id="name" type="text" name="site_name" class="form-control"   placeholder="Title must be within 70 Characters" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                                            <div class="form-group p-0 margin-bottom-16 mt-0">
                                                <label for="desc">Site Description (Characters left: 150)<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                                                <textarea id="desc"  name="site_description" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Description must be within 150 Characters" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xl-6">
                                            <div class="form-group p-0 margin-bottom-16 mt-0">
                                                <label for="keyword">Site Keywords (Separate with commas)<span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                                                <textarea id="keyword"  name="site_keywords" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3" required></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution here. I would love to find out if you have a better method.

```
SeoController.php

class SeoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        // Retrieving a model
        $seo = Seo::first();

        return view('admin-panel.seo.create', compact('seo'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Form validation
        $request->validate([
            'site_name'   =>  'required|max:70',
            'site_description'   =>  'required|max:150',
            'site_keywords'   =>  'required',
        ]);

        // Get All Request
        $input = $request->all();

        $count_rows = Seo::all()->count();

        if($count_rows == 0){
            // Record to database
            Seo::create($input);

            return redirect()->route('seo.create')
                ->with('success','Created  successfully.');
        }else {
            return redirect()->route('seo.create')
                ->with('success','Created  successfully.');
        }
    }

  }
```

My other solution. Is it possible to provide complete protection with this solution. For example, when the form tag is removed, the user is not able to submit it already. When it is not removed, it will always work. Say what.

```
$(function(){
        $('form').on('submit', function () {
            $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled', 'true');
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'unique' constraint in the form validation.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique

```
 $request->validate([
        'site_name'   =>  'required|max:70|unique:App\Site,site_name',
         ...
    ]);
```

Comment: I thought about it but do you think this way makes sense. if it is to return a warning in the end. We can't do it without returning a warning to the user.

Comment: It's for you to determine that part. You can also add a unique constraint in the database so you will make sure that whatever happens you won't have 2 rows with the same site name. You can also use where() to update the row instead of creating it if it already exists.

Comment: @ufuk You can return warning as well. `$this->validate($request, ['site_name' => 'required|max:70|unique:App\Site,site_name'], 'site_name.unique' => 'Already submitted!'] ); `

Comment: ok I get it when you add the category you want to use the nice method. But I want to add a blog. For example, I have a button called ADD BLOG. How can I prevent the user from clicking this button more than once. So when the process is finished, the user can use the ADD BLOG button again after the record is created.

Comment: @QumberRizvi yes, it may be in this method, but generally no such method has been used. I think there must be another way to do this.

Comment: You can use a session to prevent the user from adding another blog. However it can be easily worked around by using a different browser or computer.

Comment: https://ammelias-laravel.itech-theme.com/blog-create   For example, would you look at this address. password username: admin admin. For example, when he clicks here twice, he gives a warning. is this way good.

Comment: I don't see any warning.

Comment: When a new blog is created at this address, a warning is returned when the button is double clicked.

Comment: I get this message now: 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'test-1' for key 'blogs_slug_unique' (SQL: insert into `blogs` (`title`, `category_id`, `description`, `status`, `user_id`, `slug`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (test, 1,

Comment: Yes, it returns this warning, this is not my application. this friend found such a solution. Is there a better solution? I'm sorry to take your time.

Comment: This is the best server-side solution because it guarantees that a duplicate entry won't be inserted in the database. Now as I said before you can either use a validation constraint or perform a search query in the controller to make sure that the site name does not exist already.

Comment: I don't know how it provides this control on the server side. Again thanks :)

Comment: It's a unique constraint on the database. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: so I should be able to share more than one blog with the same title. What will I base on and restrict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207742/discussion-between-ufuk-and-dominique-lorre).